# How could I add or substract Two EditTex Values currency formatted with a TextWatcher?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to calculate user repayment capacity by subtracting users input from two formatted and text-watched editTexts. However, I'm getting this error:

**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100,000.0"**

I used https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText and https://github.com/zihadrizkyef/TextWatcherForMoney with no success. Here's my code:

```
ingresos.addTextChangedListener(CurrencyTextWatcher(ingresosEditText))


val IngresosNetos =
(ingresos.text.toString().toInt() - egresos.text.toString().toInt())
val formatear = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(IngresosNetos)
val formateados = "$formatear"
capacidadpagotv.text = formateados
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way for number parsing as far as i know, is '.' for decimals, and no "," for separating the thousands/millions, etc. Because of this, your strings can't be parsed to a valid numerical value.

By loooking at the [library](https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText) you are using, they provide a `getRawValue()` for

> Providing back the raw numeric values as they were input by the user, and should be treated as if it were a whole value of the users local currency. For example, if the text of the field is $13.37, this method will return a Long with a value of 1337, as penny is the lowest denomination for USD.

My advice would be to use this instead of your current approach since handling different locale/standard where '.' and ',' shift around is very hard to accomplish reliably.

**Edit**: The library's MavenCentral repo seems to be missing, so you should use the jitpack one.

```
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

and
`implementation 'com.github.BlacKCaT27:CurrencyEditText:2.0.2'`

This works for me

```
<com.blackcat.currencyedittext.CurrencyEditText
        android:id="@+id/myCurrency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

`val curencyValue = binding.myCurrency.rawValue // returns a long`

and to then set the value, use the `formatCurrency` from the same library.

```
binding.myCurrency.formatCurrency(curencyValue.toString())
```

Comment: thing is that in my country, we use ###,###.00 format. I tried the getRawValue yet couldn't use it. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by you couldn't achieve it. Did it return a bad number?

Comment: Well, don't know how to call the function, to be honest. It returned an unresolved reference error message.

Comment: You need to use the jitpack version. The mavenCentral repo seems to be missing.

Comment: I don't have any problems implementing the library, it works perfectly fine. The issue is converting the values toInt() to be able to subtract.

Comment: `getRawValue` returns a long, you can directly substract from it.

Comment: It works, yet I can't use a container with a help text when the field is empty. that's why I was using ingresos.addTextChangedListener(CurrencyTextWatcher(ingresosEditText))

Comment: Maybe try creating that error field manually, and make it invisible/visible when field is empty.